# st_within limit 1 chosing wrong polygon

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a query where I'm choosing one polygon (parcel) that intersects a point. The problem I'm having is that when I run into a parcel that has multi-geometry, it often chooses the wrong polygon because I'm limiting the query to only return one result. How can I make this query "explode" this parcel and only choose the one polygon that intersects the point?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT  b.gid,
        st_astext(st_multi((st_dump(st_union(b.geom))).geom)) as area
FROM pointschema.point a
JOIN parcelschema.polygon b on st_within(a.geom, b.geom)
LIMIT 1
```

here is what the polygon looks like (you see the point in the NE corner):
[image]

and here is what the result of the query is (orange):
[image]

for reference I'm using:

- PostgreSQL 9.5.1
- PostGIS 2.2.1
- Polygon geom: `geom geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)`
- Point geom: `geom geometry(Point,4326)`

Comment: `LIMIT 1` is unwise if you care about which feature is returned and don't provide an `ORDER BY` which will chose it. In the case of `ST_Dump`-ed geometries, you need to make the above query a virtual table (wrapped in a `FROM ( ) alias`) so you can reapply the search constraint on the parts.

Comment: that's actually the path I am currently on - creating the result set in a CTE and basically duplicating it to only select from the dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a similar example of a point intersecting a 5-part multipolygon feature (from City of Denver Parcels - see below for SQL on finding one using ST_NumGeometries):

[image]

*(maps from DBeaver spatial / geometry viewer)*

First I create a CTE to dump out all the parts of the multipolygons:

```
select 
(ST_Dump(p.geom)).geom
    from ccd."CCD_Parcels" as p 
    where 1=1
and p.schednum = '0615201001999'
```

Then bring everything together:

```
;with cte_pt as (
    select st_setsrid(St_makepoint(-104.87635, 39.70721 ), 4326) as geom 
    )

, cte_poly as (

select 
(ST_Dump(p.geom)).geom
    from ccd."CCD_Parcels" as p 
    where 1=1
and p.schednum = '0615201001999'

)

select 
*
from
cte_pt as pt 
    join cte_poly as p 
on ST_within(pt.geom, p.geom)
```

Which gives me this result:

[image]

Now I'm not sure what exact result you're trying to get - are you just looking to return the part of the multipolygon feature that intersects the point and remove the rest?

I haven't used a LIMIT 1 or a ST_Union, but hoping this gives a bit more info on working with ST_Dump and multipolygons with intersects.

To find an example to work with, I used this SQL:

```
select * from (
select 
    schednum
, st_numgeometries(geom) as geomcount
from ccd."CCD_Parcels"
    ) as d 
   where d.geomcount = '5'
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, this will work great for my problem.

Comment: @Matt also - I'm using DBeaver and the new spatial viewer for the maps...

Comment: DBeaver looks amazing. I've been looking for a viewer where I can upgrade Postgres and not have to deal with the new PGadmin!

Comment: Definitely try it out... ! It's come a long way!

Answer (score 2):

Since dumped geometries are not covered by the parent spatial index, here a slight improvement for large tables:

```
SELECT  py.gid,
        dmp.geom
FROM    (
    SELECT  a.gid,
            a.geom
    FROM    polygon AS a
    JOIN    point AS b
      ON    a.geom && b.geom
) AS    py,
        LATERAL ST_Dump(py.geom) AS dmp
JOIN    point AS pt
  ON    ST_Within(pt.geom, dmp.geom)
;
```

Here, the sub-select filters the `polygon` table using the index, to dump and relate only those polygons whose *BBOX* intersects the point(s *BBOX*)

Comment: Is this the same as doing an ST_Intersects with the points on the multipolygon data, then with that subset doing the same ST_Dump and ST_Within?

Comment: @DPSSpatial yes that's the idea exactly. I used `&&` on purpose, though, instead of `ST_Intersects`, as the latter would just add overhead.